# Cannot invoke 'setValue' with an argument list of type '(Any?, (Error?, DatabaseReference) -> Void)'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to send object of structure to firebase.

```
struct commentsData{
        var commentsText:String
        var commentTime:String
        var commentDay:String
        var commentMonth:String
        var commentYear:String
    }

    var data = commentsData(commentsText: "", commentTime: "", commentDay: "", commentMonth: "", commentYear: "")

    Database.database().reference().child("CommentData").child(commentId).setValue(data){
                     (error:Error?, ref:DatabaseReference) in


                }
```

What changes i should do to work it out.

Comment: Don't name your properties like `commentTime`, `commentDay` and simply use `time`, `day`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can't add objects directly like that, instead you have to pass the data as dictionary. So you can add following code inside your structure,

```
var dict:[String:String] {
    return [
        "commentsText": commentsText,
        "commentTime": commentTime,
        "commentDay": commentDay,
        "commentMonth": commentMonth,
        "commentYear": commentYear
    ]
}
```

and then

```
var data = commentsData(commentsText: "1", commentTime: "1", commentDay: "1", commentMonth: "1", commentYear: "1")


Database.database().reference().child("CommentData").child(commentId).setValue(data.dict) {  (error, ref) in
          // continue here 
        }
```

Comment: On adding the dict to the structure it gives error on the variables.

Comment: Value of type 'String' does not conform to expected dictionary value type 'AnyObject'

Comment: change to var dict: [String: String]

Answer (score 1):

You need to write the completion without types

```
var data:[String:Any] = ["key":"value"] //
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("CommentData").child(commentId).setValue(data) { (err, ref) in

}
```

Comment: Your code is giving a different compile time error Ambiguous reference to member 'setValue(_:withCompletionBlock:)'